# Bootstrap's 'select' not Working in smaller devices

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've been doing a project and I've been stuck on one thing and that is really frustrating me, i.e bootstrap's 'select' not working in mobile and tab devices. I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988049/select-drop-down-does-not-work-in-mobile-device-when-apply-bootstrap?rq=1) solution on stackoverflow but this didn't workout for me.

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="religion">Religion:</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="race">Race:</label>

            <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="country">Country:</label>

            <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Please help me make this Work!

Comment: For me its working. I can use select. are you using js and css ot bs?? see https://jsfiddle.net/pov2jp22/1/

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes, I've used them as above.

Comment: Check my fiddle, is it what you want? or check console that are you getting any error.

Comment: Maybe you need to add the `form` tag? https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/es4fg13q/1/

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted. When I resize the window it works, but when I check to see on console it won't open.

Comment: @Aziz Adding <form> tag won't do anything. I have made it without form tag.

Answer (score 0):

Today I ran into same issue.

I then figured out that the only class used was `col-sm-*`, and no `col-xs-*`  (mobile devices) class was used on elements, which resulted in the form inputs being inaccessible on mobile devices.

Along with `col-sm-*`, add `col-xs-*` to your class list to make it work on mobile devices.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I found out that, when you load the Bootstrap css and js in the head, instead of right before the closing body tag (as mentioned in the documentation of bootstrap), it will work.

With other words, to make it work in mobile devices, you have to load the bootstrap javascripts first.