# ng2-bootstrap select and radios loose functionality on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular2-forms

There is a weird behavior, i have a select and two radios that works perfectly on desktop browsers but in mobile they just loose their functionality... let me show this with an image:

*In desktop, you can see the indicative arrows of a select*

[image: In desktop, you can see the indicative arrows of a select]

*But in mobile no, and is impossible to open the select "tapping" the field*

[image]

Of course here is the code:

```
<section class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div
            class="form-group col-xs-12"
            [ngClass]="{'col-md-8': options === 'eval', 'col-md-offset-2': options === 'eval', 'col-md-5': options === 'compare'}">
            <select
                class="form-control"
                name="categoryOne"
                [(ngModel)]="TitleOne.category"
                required>
                <option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category">{{category}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this problem on iOS? I had the same on iOS; adding these imports in the app.module fixed this

```
// 
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/nb';
```

Comment: In IOS, and Chrome for android. Let me try this. ¿Do you import something special in the `imports` just use that two bare lines?

Comment: Just the other needed imports for my app (I added these two lines when testing this on iOS/Safari); I'm using angular 2.3; ng2-bootstrap latest version

Comment: Check also this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988049/select-drop-down-does-not-work-in-mobile-device-when-apply-bootstrap?rq=1